# debian 9 php 7.0 iconv convert from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-2

Tags: php, iconv

I need to convert UTF-8 to ISO-8859-2. I spend a lot of hours but without effect. 
**simple code**

```
$data = 'Ala była zła że się przewróciła';
//$data = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-2', $data);
$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'ISO-8859-2','UTF-8');
die(var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($data)));
```

I use `die()` to print encoding. Byt this detection returns `bool(false)`.
If I comment line with converting mb_detect prints that is "UTF-8".

Why I cannot convert to ISO-8859-2? any special configuration in php.ini is needed or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the last line to this:

```
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($data, "ISO-8859-2, UTF-8"));
```

The 2nd param will provide it an `encoding list` to choose from.

Output:

```
string 'ISO-8859-2' (length=10)
```

Comment: Ok, I changed output encoding to 'Windows-1250" and works. Printer producer misguides :/